# ASP.NET CORE 2.0 - cURL file upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to use https://dropfile.to/api API service. I need to have the file upload form that basically gets the IFormFile and uploads it to the API. The problem is that I'm getting strange request with the status 2 which means "Unknown error". At their site it says that I should be using:

`curl -F "file=@screenshot.jpg" https://d1.dropfile.to/upload`

How to perform such thing in ASP.NET? I tried every solution I found on this site and none of them worked.

What I got so far:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFile(string address, IFormFile file)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            var data = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)file.OpenReadStream().Length);
            var bytes = new ByteArrayContent(data);
            var multiContent = new MultipartFormDataContent {
                {
                    bytes, "file", file.FileName
                }
            };

            return await client.PostAsync(address, multiContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Working version of HTML form only:

```
<form action="https://d3.dropfile.to/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple="multiple">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I can't use the HTML form version because I keep track of the files that are uploaded.

Valid response:

```
{

    "files": [
        "eBooks.txt",
        "znOu9ZB",
        "wUFTssk",
        "14323"
        ],
    "status": 0,
    "url": "https:\/\/dropfile.to\/znOu9ZB",
    "access_key": "wUFTssk"
}
```

Failed response:

```
{
    "files":{
        "1":"ZW2FSA8",
        "2":"XzBpM6w"
    },
    "status":2
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Nugget package called [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). My code looks like:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://d1.dropfile.to/");
var request = new RestRequest("upload", Method.POST);
request.AddFileBytes("file", file, $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.zip", "application/zip");

var response = client.Execute(request).Content;
```